# BadRequest 400 HttpParams Angular 4.3

Tags: angular, http, typescript, http-request

Estou utilizando a nova biblioteca do angular para fazer requisições, a `HttpClient`. Junto com o angular 4+ estou utilizando aqui na empresa para o *backend*, Java com Spring (boot).

O problema está ocorrendo na hora de fazer uma requisição GET para o *backend*, o `HttpParams`, usado com `HttpClient` para passar parâmetros, não faz o *replace* das variáveis e assim o *backend* nega a requisição.

Ex.: URL *backend* (Java): **`controller/obterByCodOne/{codOne}/codTwo/{codTwo}`**

Ex.: URL *frontend* (Angular): **`http://localhost:8080/controller/obterByCodOne/:codOne/codTwo/:codTwo`**

Código:

```
let params = new HttpParams()
            .set('codOne', codOne)
            .set('codTwo', codTwo);
```

Resultado (errado): **`http://localhost:8080/controller/obterByCodOne/:codOne/codTwo/:codTwo?codOne=valueA&codTwo=valueB`**

O `HttpParams` não está substituindo a variável, mas concatenando.

Em outro projetos AngularJS era substituído o valor normalmente usando o `$resource`. Ao invés de ter q ficar concatenando pedaços de URL's com as variáveis até chegar ao um resultado final.

Enfim... Estou nesse empasse. Ou não estou entendendo o uso do HttpParams ou não estou sabendo usa-lo.

Comment: Tentou deixar a url somente `controller/obterByCodOne`?

Comment: @LucasCosta já sim. Desse jeito retorna 404 :\

Comment: @LINQ qual arquivo mais vc precisa? Só coloquei isso pq achei q fosse suficiente.

Comment: Todo link que encontro mostra montando a url na mão. Ex: http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/use-angular-httpclient-post-put-delete-data-springboot-rest-apis-angular-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como minhas URLS estavam em um arquivo de URLS padrão, eu não poderia concatenar. Acabei adotando um padrão de para minhas URLS e cada parametro é seguido de dois pontos, exemplo: http://minhaurl.com/:idA/:nomeB e no meu serviço eu dou um replace. No backend em Java eu utilizo @Pathvariable nos meus parâmetros, sendo q o @RequestMapping eu usei minha url assim http://minhaurl.com/{idA}/{nomeB}.

Neste cenário, os parâmetros devem ser obrigatórios. Em um caso de filtro com parâmetros opicionais eu adoto a prática de usar DTO (Data Transfer Object).

Espero ajudar tbm!

Answer (score 1):

Já ocorreu este problema comigo. Caso não consigo usar o HttpParams, faça uma manipulação de String e adicione manualmente os params.
ex.:

```
  public getPessoas(idade){

       this.http.get(URL_API+"?idade="+idade)
       ...
  }
```

obs.:

- URL_API - É a url da api
- "?idade" - É a forma manual de adicionar um parâmetro.
- idade - variável que representa o valor que estou passando como parâmetro.

Caso queira adicionar um novo parametro, adicione um "&" e passe o novo parâmetro.
ex.:

```
this.http.get(URL_API+"?idade="+idade+"&peso="+peso)
```

Esta não é a melhor solução, mas funciona!
Espero que tenha ajudado :)

Comment: Se eu usar o HttpParams ele já faz isso pra mim. O problema é que eu defino as variáveis no meu back na própria url, como no exemplo que eu dei a cima. Mas provavelmente eu vá optar por essa opção mesmo. Estou analisando o melhor caso e depois comento aqui. Vlw cara!

Answer (score 1):

O `HttpParams` são os `QueryParams`, os parâmetros de url `?`.

Use interpolação de String do TypeScript para montar sua url.

```
get(codOne: number, codTwo: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:8080/controller/obterByCodOne/${codOne}/codTwo/${codTwo}`);
}
```

Comment: Encontrei uma outra solução. Mas obrigado!